# Spring Boot Controller endpoint and ModelAttribute deep access

Tags: spring, spring-boot, binding, controller, modelattribute

I would like to know how to access a deep collection class attribute in a GET request. My endpoint maps my query strings through @ModelAttribute annotation:

Given that:

```
public class MyEntity
{
    Set<Item> items;
    Integer status;
    // getters setters
}

public class Item
{
    String name;
    // getters setters
}
```

And my GET request: localhost/entities/?status=0&items[0].name=Garry

Produces bellow behavior?

```
@RequestMapping(path = "/entities", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public List<MyEntity> findBy(@ModelAttribute MyEntity entity) {
     // entity.getItems() is empty and an error is thrown: "Property referenced in indexed property path 'items[0]' is neither an array nor a List nor a Map."
}
```

Should my "items" be an array, List or Map? If so, there´s alternatives to keep using as Set?

Comment: is your entity mapped with hibernate ? please include more details where is your return statement ?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there is some problem with the `Set<Item>`.

If you want to use Set for the `items` collection you have to initialize it and add some items:

e.g. like this:

```
public class MyEntity {
    private Integer status;
    private Set<Item> items;

    public MyEntity() {
        this.status = 0;
        this.items = new HashSet<>();
        this.items.add(new Item());
        this.items.add(new Item());
    }
//getters setters
}
```

but then you will be able to set only the values of this 2 items:

This will work: `http://localhost:8081/map?status=1&items[0].name=asd&items[1].name=aaa`

This will not work: `http://localhost:8081/map?status=1&items[0].name=asd&items[1].name=aaa&items[2].name=aaa`

it will say: `Invalid property 'items[2]' of bean class MyEntity.`

However if you switch to List:

```
public class MyEntity {
    private Integer status;
    private List<Item> items;
}
```

both urls map without the need to initialize anything and for various number of items.

note that I didn't use `@ModelAttribute`, just set the class as paramter

```
@GetMapping("map")//GetMapping is just a shortcut for RequestMapping
public MyEntity map(MyEntity myEntity) {
    return myEntity;
}
```

**Offtopic**

Mapping a complex object in Get request sounds like a code smell to me. 
Usually Get methods are used to get/read data and the url parameters are used to specify the values that should be used to filter the data that has to be read.

if you want to insert or update some data use POST, PATCH or PUT and put the complex object that you want to insert/update in the request body as JSON(you can map that in the Spring Controller with `@RequestBody`).

Comment: Thanks @Evgeni. Sorry to reply you too late. I Changed my approach but i´ll try your first url.
Yes it seems a code smell but I´m using Spring Data Example feature and it maps my queries into a helper entity and then transform each non null attribute in a WHERE clause of my sql query. For my admin page features it is very helpful.